# How to flash/change a UIButton borderColor with animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uibutton

I have UIButton and I want to add a continuously flash/change borderColor animation to it. So it should start with no border color then after 1 sec change to green, then repeat.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this can help

```
    targetButton.layer.borderWidth = 8.0
    let color: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderColor")
    color.fromValue = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    color.toValue = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    color.duration = 0.5
    color.autoreverses = true
    self.targetButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    self.targetButton.layer.addAnimation(color, forKey: "")
```

sorry, I forgot to set button border width. 
you can try again.

Comment: please try again and tell me the result.

Comment: It's working, but not smooth, when the color is set to blue, it turn back to clearColor, but without fade animation...

Comment: try again. I added new line *color. autoreverses = true*